# Why does JavaScript prototype method output differently for the same property?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Can someone explain to me like I lack basic brain function why `fluffy.age` outputs `3` while `muffin.age` outputs `4`? Is it simply because `fluffy` is defined prior to the age change?

I'm extremely new to coding but already have a decent grasp on everything else JavaScript; However, the prototype idea still makes little sense to me.

```js
function Cat(name, color, meow) {
  this.name = name;
  this.color = color;
}

Cat.prototype.age = 3;
var fluffy = new Cat("Fluffy", "White");
console.log(fluffy.age);

Cat.prototype = {
  age: 4
};

console.log(fluffy.age);
var muffin = new Cat("Muffin", "Brown");
console.log(muffin.age);
```

Comment: Yes. You're modifying the prototype after you've created an instance. That doesn't restroactively change the instance. You created the instance (copy) `fluffy` based on a previous `Cat.prototype`.

Comment: You're not **modifying** the prototype, you're **replacing** it. Instances keep a reference to the constructor's prototype *when they are created*. So assigning a new prototype object to the constructor later doesn't change the prototype for instances that are already created. I.e. `fluffy.__proto__ !== muffin.__proto__`.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the prototype after you created an instance from that. So that instance does not contain updated prototype properties.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Cat(name, color, meow) {
          this.name = name;
          this.color = color;
        }

        Cat.prototype.age = 3;

        var fluffy = new Cat("Fluffy", "White");

        console.log('Before update', fluffy.age);

        fluffy.age = 4;

        console.log('After update', fluffy.age);

        var muffin = new Cat("Muffin", "Brown");

        console.log('New object', muffin.age);
```

When you create a new instance from a class and if you want to change the values in that instance, you need to use that instance not the original class